# Binding within a block

Tags: ruby, binding, block

I'd like to use a block within method `initialize`. With this code:

```
class Settlement
  attr_reader :url, :parameters
  def initialize(&block)
    instance_eval block.call
  end
  def parameters(x) ; @parameters = x; end
  def url(x) ; @url = x;  end
end

settlement = Settlement.new do
  url "https://xxxxx"
  parameters("ffff")
end
```

I got the error message below:

> NoMethodError - undefined method parameters

Any ideas?

Comment: You do realize that you're overwriting methods from `attr_reader`, right?

Comment: You're right.... I should change the name of my methods. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `instance_eval block.call` `block.call` is evaluated *before* `instance_eval` is called. This means the block is called without the instance binding.

This should work:

```
def initialize(&block)
  instance_eval &block
end
```

Comment: fixed ! thank you . I will validate it in 3 minutes ~